# How to turn on/offf camera flash light with ARKit?

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I am using a `ARSCNView` for displaying AR experiences that augment the camera view with 3D `SceneKit` content.

[ARSession](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsession) shared object that manages the device camera, but in `ARSession`  i can't found any option for flash light.

Is there any way to turn on/off camera flash light?

How to manage camera with `ARKit`?

How to change camera position front and back?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
func toggleTorch(on: Bool) {
        guard let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.video) 
        else {return}

        if device.hasTorch {
            do {
                try device.lockForConfiguration()

                if on == true {
                    device.torchMode = .on // set on
                } else {
                    device.torchMode = .off // set off
                }

                device.unlockForConfiguration()
            } catch {
                print("Torch could not be used")
            }
        } else {
            print("Torch is not available")
        }
    }
```

Call this as

toggleTorch(on: true) of toggleTorch(on: false)

ref: Hacking with Swift

Comment: Could you write a bit more about what happens vs what you expect to happen?

Comment: can you explain how to change camera position in `ARKit`?

Comment: What is `on` referring to?

Answer (score 3):

The other answer covers the torch, so as to your camera position question...

There’s no way to select a camera for ARKit; that is, ARKit selects the camera for you.

- When you use world tracking, ARKit always selects the back-facing, wide-angle camera (not the telephoto or dual camera on devices so equipped).
- When you use face tracking (iPhone X only), ARKit always uses the front-facing TrueDepth camera.

Answer (score 3):

If your torch is being closed by OS right after you turned it on, what you need to do is; not to turn the torch on right after starting ARKit session. You should turn on the torch after some time. I start the AR session in viewDidLoad() and tried the turn on the torch in viewDidAppear() but OS was closing it right after. So, I was able to make it work like this;

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {  
         super.viewDidAppear(animated)  
         DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) { [weak self] in            
              self?.toggleFlash() 
         }  
}
```